# Why can i not use a default value in def if no argument is given

Tags: python

Why do i get an error when running this code and just hitting enter when asked for an input?
within `def main(x=3)` , why is it not defaulting to x=3 in the body of the function when I do not give input when prompted ie. just hitting the space bar when asked 'what is 'x'' if i enter an int value it works and uses that value for x, but the default x=3 in the brackets of main is not used if no argument is passed when prompted

```
def main(x=3):
    x = int(input("What's x? "))
    print("x squaredis", square(x))
    
def square(n):
    return n * n

main()
```

Why does it not default to 9 in this example

Comment: Because you overwrote ```x``` with the ```x = int(input("What's x? "))``` line.

Answer (score 0):

If you give an invalid input like a space, the `int()` call should give an error and an exception will be raised instead of setting the value of `x`, so a basic way to achieve the behavior you described would be

```py
def main(x=3):
    try:
        x = int(input("What's x? "))
    except ValueError:
        pass
    print("x squaredis", square(x))
    
def square(n):
    return n * n

main()
```

If you input a valid int, it will overwrite `x`, otherwise the exception will propagate up and be ignored, leaving `x` as its default.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `main()`, `x` is assigned the value `3` immediately on entry; if you added `print(x)` *before* the assignment to `x`, you would see `3` written to standard output.

However, as soon as you *assign* to `x` inside the function, whatever value it had (whether the default value or an explicit value provided by the caller) no longer matters; the only thing that *does* matter is what `int` returns, which is determined by the value returned by `input`. If `input` returns the empty string, `int` doesn't return at all, but raises an exception instead, because `''` is not a valid integer literal.